# Synfony 3 + Vich upload bundle - Failed to set metadata before uploading the file

Tags: vichuploaderbundle

My problem is to retrieve metadata before uploading the file.

My config file:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        media:
            uri_prefix:         /uploads/
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads'
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

I have an entity MEDIA :

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

    **
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @Vich\Uploadable
     */
    class Media
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         *
         * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="media", fileNameProperty="fileName",originalName="originalFileName")
         *
         * @var File
         */
         private $file;

         /**
          * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
          */
         private $fileName;

         /**
          * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
          */
         private $originalFileName;

         /**
          * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
          */
         private $updatedAt;

         /**
          * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file
          *
          * @return Media
          */
         public function setFile(File $file = null)
         {
             $this->file = $file;

             if ($file) {
                 $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
             }

             return $this;
         }

         /**
          * @return File|null
          */
         public function getFile()
         {
             return $this->file;
         }

         /**
          * @param string $fileName
          *
          * @return Media
          */
         public function setFileName($fileName)
         {
             $this->fileName = $fileName;

             return $this;
         }

         /**
          * @return string|null
          */
         public function getFileName()
         {
             return $this->fileName;
         }

         /**
          * Get id
          *
          * @return integer
          */
         public function getId()
         {
             return $this->id;
         }

         /**
          * Set updatedAt
          *
          * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
          *
          * @return Media
          */
         public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
         {
             $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

             return $this;
         }

         /**
          * Get updatedAt
          *
          * @return \DateTime
          */
         public function getUpdatedAt()
         {
             return $this->updatedAt;
         }

         /**
          * Set originalFileName
          *
          * @param string $originalFileName
          *
          * @return Media
          */
         public function setOriginalFileName($originalFileName)
         {
             $this->originalFileName = $originalFileName;

             return $this;
         }

         /**
          * Get originalFileName
          *
          * @return string
          */
         public function getOriginalFileName()
         {
             return $this->originalFileName;
         }
     }
```

And here is my controller:

```
   /**
     * Creates a new media entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="media_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $media = new Media();
        $form = $this->createForm(MediaType::class, $media);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($media);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute(
                'media_list'
            );
        }

        return $this->render(
            'media/new.html.twig',
            [
                'media' => $media,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ]
        );
    }
```

And my form:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Created by PhpStorm.
     * User: rafael
     * Date: 4/10/17
     * Time: 12:46 PM
     */

    namespace AppBundle\Form;

    use AppBundle\Entity\Media;
    use AppBundle\Entity\MediaDescriptionHelper;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class MediaType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('file', FileType::class)
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'btn-primary btn-block']
                ]);
        }

        /**
         * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Media::class]);
        }
    }
```

The problem is with the mapping of these values :

@Vich\UploadableField(mapping="media", fileNameProperty="fileName",originalName="originalFileName")

When I submit my form these values are 'null' :

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO media (file_name, original_file_name, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["get_image_resultat_sans_cache2.php.jpeg", null, "2017-04-12 10:11:56"]:

I have these issues with all parameters :

(https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md)

The UploadableField annotation has a few options. They are as follows:

**mapping**: required, the mapping name specified in the bundle configuration to use;
**fileNameProperty**: required, the property that will contain the name of the uploaded file;
**size**: the property that will contain the size in bytes of the uploaded file;
**mimeType**: the property that will contain the mime type of the uploaded file;
**originalName**: the property that will contain the origilal name of the uploaded file.

I don't see what I did wrong...

Here is my Media (entity) after the form is submitted :

Media {#403 ▼
  -id: null
  -file: UploadedFile {#15 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "get_image_resultat_sans_cache2.php.jpeg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 203751
    -error: 0
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php9xsTdF"
    basename: "php9xsTdF"
    pathname: "/tmp/php9xsTdF"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/php9xsTdF"
    aTime: 2017-04-12 10:11:56
    mTime: 2017-04-12 10:11:56
    cTime: 2017-04-12 10:11:56
    inode: 6160452
    size: 203751
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  -fileName: null
  -originalFileName: null

It seems that's a problem when set metadata before uploading the file...

Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Symfony version: 3.2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of VichUploaderBundle do you use?

The documentation for the annotations refers to the dev-master one, while the stable one (1.5.3) doesn't support annotation for metadata out of the box.

You can see that Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\UploadableField.php in the 1.5.3 version handles only annotations 'mapping' and 'fileNameProperty'.

While in the dev-master, it handles those and size, mimeType and originalName.

Same thing with Vich\UploaderBundle\Metadata\Driver\AnnotationDriver

If you want to achieve this in the 1.5.3 version you need to create an eventListener.

Here are the event triggered by Vich : https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/1.5.3/Event/Events.php

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer :)

I set my attribute manually in the entity without a listener and it's working perfect.

Because the fieldType (->add('file', FileType::class)) contains all I need.